# NSubstitute use real instance of a class as substitute, except one method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Is there any built-in way in NSubstitute for mocking a class with its instance except for few methods?

In example I want to preserve the whole functionality of the instance, but check if a method gets called with particular parameters.

To do that actually I do

```
public class Wrapper: IInterface
{
    public IInterface real;
    public IInterface sub;

    public void Wrapper(IIterface realInstance, IIterface nsubstitute)
    {
        real = realInstance;
        sub = nsubstitute;
    }

    public void MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways()
    {
        real.MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways();
    }

    public intMethodToBeTested(int a)
    {
        return sub.MethodToBeTested();
    }
}
```

The reason for that is that I'm testing stuff complex enough that I can't simply create wrappers manually, that's time consuming and error-prone. It would be nice if Nsubstitute allows for something like:

```
IIterface realMock = NSubstitute.Mock< IIterface>( new RealClass());

realMock.MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways(); // regular logic
realMock.MethodToBeTested(4).Returns( 3); // overrides the method to always returns 3
```

but I did not find any documentation for doing that so far.

Comment: mock the actual class provided it is not sealed. The members to be overridden need to be virtual though in order for it to work.

Comment: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/

Comment: Take special note of the warnings associated with using partial mocks/subs.

Comment: What is wrong with testing actual implementation?

Comment: The implementation is tested, I need to test the class using it and verify that finally a method is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your situation correctly, you have a class you're testing which takes the `IIterface` as a dependency and you want to ensure the `MethodToBeTested(int)` method is being called by the class you're testing.

This can be done using the `.ForPartsOf<T>()` method of generating the mock. This generates a "partial mock", which will call the underlying class implementation unless you provide an override.  It comes with a big requirement, though: The methods you want to override (or ensure were called) must be `virtual` (or `abstract` if defined in a base class).

Once you have the mock, then you can use `.Received()` to assert that methods on the mock were called (or not called, if you use `.DidNotReceive()`).

You don't actually need to override the behavior of `MethodToBeTested(int)` if you want the base implementation to be used.

**Here's a concrete example, based on your sample code:**

For the dependency, you have a `RealClass` that implements the interface `IIterface` and you want to ensure `MethodToBeTested(int)` was called. So those might look like this:

```
public interface IIterface
{
    void MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways();
    int MethodToBeTested(int a);
}

public class RealClass: IIterface
{
    public void MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways()
    { }

    public virtual int MethodToBeTested(int a)
    { return a; }
}
```

Then you have the class you're actually testing, which uses the `IIterface` as a dependency:

```
public class ClassThatUsesMockedClass
{
    private readonly IIterface _other;

    public ClassThatUsesMockedClass(IIterface other)
    {
        _other = other;
    }

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        _other.MethodThatShouldWorkAsAlways();

        _other.MethodToBeTested(5);
    }
}
```

Now, you want to test that `DoSomeStuff()` actually calls `MethodToBeTested()`, so you'll need to create a partial mock of `SomeClass` and then use `.Received()` to validate it was called:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestThatDoSomeStuffCallsMethodToBeTested()
    {
        //Create your mock and class being tested
        IIterface realMock = Substitute.ForPartsOf<RealClass>();
        var classBeingTested = new ClassThatUsesMockedClass(realMock);

        //Call the method you're testing
        classBeingTested.DoSomeStuff();

        //Assert that MethodToBeTested was actually called
        realMock.Received().MethodToBeTested(Arg.Any<int>());

    }
```